# Function $0$ after a certain t is equivalent to one defined on a compact set?

Tags: compactness

Let's define the following set of functions:

$$C_c(\mathbb{R}) = \{f \in C(\mathbb{R}) | f(t) = 0, \forall t \text{ s.t. } |t| \geq T, T \geq 0\} $$

Then, can I  say that for a general $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R}) $, $f$ is defined in $[-T,T]$ ? Because actually a general function is defined in all $\mathbb{R}$, but it is $0 \text{ } \forall \text{ } t \text{ } \geq T$.

(I need to say that because I want to use the fact that $f$ is defined in a compact set).

Comment: While I don't think that it's necessarily wrong to say that $f$ is defined in $[-T, T]$, I think that it would be better to say that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and [supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) in $[-T, T]$. You can also talk about the restriction of $f$ to $[-T,T]$ (usually denoted by $f \mid_{[-T,T]}$), which is clearly well-defined as $f$ is defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In either case though, you need to be aware that $f$ and its restriction to $[-T, T]$ are *not* the same function, strictly speaking.

Comment: Because I need to prove that if $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous. So I was thinking of using the fact that if $f$ is continuous and defined on a compact set, then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: In that case, I would probably write something along the lines of: Since $f$ is continuous and vanishes outside of $[-T, T]$, it suffices to prove that its restriction to $[-T,T]$ is uniformly continuous...

Comment: If that's the case, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-T, T]$ by Cantor's theorem in analysis.